# How to access the contents of the closure from the outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

I use the following code to read the file line by line.
But the content of the line is in a closure, what can I do to access the contents of the line outside?The module I am using is the internal module of node.js

```
  var fs=require("fs")
 function readFirstLine(){
    var firstfile = [];
    readline = require('readline');

    var rd = readline.createInterface({
        input: fs.createReadStream('somefile.txt'),
        output: process.stdout,
        terminal: false
    });

    rd.on('line', function(line) {
        console.log(line)  
    }
    );

}
    readFirstLine()
```

Comment: You can take help of async and await here.

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. This is the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push each line to external array, but you won't know when the readline finish to read the file.

The easiest way, with `async/await`.

[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)